# Can't install python libpng

Tags: python

I am trying to instal a Python module called libpng. It's not in the Python Package index, so I have downloaded and unpacked the .7z file into the scripts folder and added the complete path to sys.path. I am trying to install with pip but getting the error 'could not find any downloads'. I have searched for a tutorial but can't find anything to help, I am quite new to programming. Could anyone point me in the right direction please.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't say this is on a windows 10 system.

Comment: Are you behind a firewall or a proxy?

Answer (score -1):

I assume you OS is Ubuntu, then in terminal(Alt+Ctrl+T) run the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install libpng-dev
```

Comment: Why are you assuming his OS is Ubuntu?